# Variational derivative of $\Phi_a(-\partial^2 - m_0^2 - \Sigma)\Phi_a$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Let me refer to the below link
[http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-17-phi4on.pdf](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/%7Ekleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-17-phi4on.pdf)

In Eq: 18.40, $\Gamma[\Phi_a, \Sigma]$ is given as,
$\Gamma[\Phi_a,\Sigma] = NA_{coll}[\Sigma] + \frac{1}{2}\int d^4x \Phi_a(-\partial^2 - m_0^2 - \Sigma)\Phi_a$

Note: $A_{coll}[\Sigma]$ is purely a function of $\Sigma$

The in Eq. 18.41, the author states:
$\Gamma_{\Phi_a \Phi_b} = (-\partial^2 - m_0^2 - \Sigma)\delta_{ab}$

My question is, how is the above possible?

In the first term, since $A_{coll}[\Sigma]$ is purely a function of $\Sigma$, we have $\frac{\delta A_{coll}[\Sigma]}{\delta \Phi_a} = 0$.

So, the first term is not an issue. The issue is with the second term.

In the second term, the factor $\frac{\delta (\partial^2 \Phi_a)}{\delta \Phi_a} = 0$.

This means:
$\Gamma_{\Phi_a \Phi_b} = (- m_0^2 - \Sigma)\delta_{ab}$
and not
$\Gamma_{\Phi_a \Phi_b} = (-\partial^2 - m_0^2 - \Sigma)\delta_{ab}$

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you get $\frac{\delta(\partial^2\Phi_a)}{\delta\Phi_b}=\partial^2 \delta_{a,b}$ instead of what you wrote?

Comment: I don't think so. As an example, when one determines the Euler Lagrange equations of motion, one takes $\phi$ and $\partial \phi$ as independent variables. Logically, in functionals, we wish to determine the optimal function, $\Phi$. Hence, one would take $\Phi$ and $\partial \Phi$ to be independent functions, so that one can arrive upon the differential equation, which when solved, gives the optimal $\Phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment above is true.
The total differential

$\frac{\delta(\partial^2\Phi_a)}{\delta \Phi_b}=\partial^2\delta_{ab}$

Euler Lagrange equation can be written as

$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta\phi}=0$ or in other words
$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\phi)}=0$

One then need to pay attention to the difference between partial derivative and differential. For the equation including $\partial \mathcal{L}$ one consider $\partial_\mu \phi$ and $\phi$ as independant variables, while it is not the case when considering the differential $\delta \mathcal{L}$.